# Could a 1,000x10,000 mile strip between mountain ranges be drier than the lands either side?

Tags: climate, geography, weather

On an Earth-like planet, two roughly parallel mountain ranges run for several thousand miles across a continent, with a gap of several hundred miles in between.

[image]

I am aware that mountains can create a "rain shadow" on one side since atmospheric moisture will precipitate as it is blown over a mountain, leaving the far side drier.

Could such a phenomenon consistently happen on this parallel set of mountains, such that the far north and far south are wet and forested, while the middle section is more like a savanna?

It occurs to me that this that prevailing winds would have to be coming into the strip from both sides, causing a net air flow either upwards or along the strip to emerge at the sea. What would be the consequences of this in terms of weather and climate?

Main question: is such a climate possible? What other geographic features would have to be present to produce this pattern of wind and rain?

Comment: Depends on the scale (maybe of the planet itself? because you likely need to be looking at the global convection currents that establish the prevailing wind patterns? which may limit *"where"* you can put this in a global context) .. but I suppose it might be possible if there were two seperate stable air cells either side.

Comment: When you ask "is this possible," how much science are you looking for? Climate is by far the most complex type of question we get here. To give you scientific certainly we'd need to know a LOT more about the oceans, the world's hydrology and geology, and atmospheric conditions. To give you an example, there's a [40cm difference](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0146631361900442) between the Atlantic and Pacific sea levels. Depending on the altitude of those plains and where this is located, you might have a river.

Comment: BTW, what you're asking for isn't unbelievable (whether or not it's possible). The higher the elevation of the plains and mountains, and the narrower the gap, the more believable it gets. However, what you'll get will be more desert than anything else.

Comment: Have you looked at the orientation of mountains with respect to the rain shadows they create? There is a pattern to them... Also, how did your mountain range form? that is a very unusual configuration.

Comment: peru current + double rain shadow region + sandwiched bet andes mt and the chilean mt + el nino = atacama desert (driest place)

Comment: @user6760 looking at it on Google maps the Atacama desert doesn't really fit, to the east you have green to the west ocean, there is not another green belt on the other side, Mendoza province a bit further south comes closer with a green belt along the coast to the west and further to east melding slowly into greener areas of Argentina .. the way the Atacama desert suddenly ends and goes green suggests two different side by side prevailing weather cells/patterns there reversing the rain shadow from the Andes to me? but I'm not familiar with the appropriate meteorological information.

Comment: @JBH that 40cm diff is not physical height as in sea level, it's about average atmospheric pressure over the oceans being notable (40cm air weight equals about 2.7 Hg microns or  about 0.36 Pa - over the ocean this does stand for a statistically noticeable difference, but it's not too damn serious). Careful with numbers please.

Comment: Another option is to not fiddle with climate at all, but to make this "plains" area unable to sustain forests because of recurrent floodings from seawater that made the land too salty to grow a forest.

Comment: just as a side note to get that shape your best bet is a rift valley, there is not many other ways to get two parrallel mountains around a valley.

Comment: The Olympic rainshadow in Washinton State, USA might provide some useful analogoes.  It's very small but occurs between two Mountain ranges near seattle.  Its a very different situation though because one of the Mountain ranges is very small

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, here's a potential rough answer for you.

Your strip of desert sandwiched between two green areas is located between two Hadley Cells.

Which means it's on the equator, you want warm air flowing toward your two mountain ranges from both sides (top and bottom in your map) so the equator is the only option.

[image]

You also want that warm air to be carrying moisture so you need large bodies of water (we're talking oceans here just in case that wasn't clear) to the north and south so this warm air can load up with that moisture.

This way you have two prevailing wind patterns of warm moisture laden air traveling from two directions towards each other to dump it out on their respective mountain ranges giving you your rain shadow desert between them.

So if your rough map is oriented with north at the top and south at the bottom it can kind of work for this, if you have oceans top and bottom of it rather than the sides.

Comment: +1 just for the phrase, "rough answer."

Comment: @JBH well, it is just a bodge job of cobbled together vague memory and the first useful image I found, I might have said *"good enough for government work",* but not sure anyone here would get that ;p

Comment: This looks like a good answer, thanks. A detail I forgot to add -- my planet has a greater axial tilt than Earth. Maybe about 40 degrees. Would this impact the formation of Hadley Cells? (In the limit of 90 degrees my intuition says this would all look very different.)

Comment: PS @Pelinore [?](https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2FonA_sBGNpyc%2Fmaxresdefault.jpg&f=1&nofb=1&ipt=5efafee2b916c82421287e16a972717c07d322c38c22039feba7144878f4b1ed&ipo=images)

Comment: @spraff Would never have occured to worry about that were it my world :) I wouldn't think so but I don't really know > if I was guessing now I'd been asked I'd say "maybe-no", the precise shape (length / width) maybe, direction of wind flows in them no, that there would be other than two either side of the equator no, so I'd presume this answer would still be ok .. but I would be guessing there.

Comment: between the Hadley cells will just bring more rain, you want it between the Hadley and Ferrel cell, so little moisture is coming in. different prevailing winds and coastal effects can supply the areas outside the valley.

Comment: @spraff axial tilt doesn't impact the Hadley cells much, not till you get close to 90 degrees, the speed of the planets rotation is the major influence.

Comment: @John that is actually relevant -- my planet spins differently from Earth. Can you direct me to some more information about that?

Comment: @John *"between the Hadley cells will just bring more rain"* Did you miss the rain shadow bit? tall mountain ranges are the mechanic he's using to provide his desert, all the rain they bring is meant to be dumped out before the air gets over those mountains so how much isn't an issue, with one ferrel cell on one side the moisture may be taken away before dropping so he won't get the lush green both sides he wants // *"axial tilt .. rotation"* cheers, Mars seems to have a different cell distribution for whatever reason but I didn't find a spin and tilt model to play with on my brief search  ;)

Comment: @John Cast your eye along the two 30° lines across the globe and take another look at the cell diagram above, between a hadley and a ferrel cell you have cold dry air falling pushing the lower air that picks up moisture as it warms away to the sides, the ground (or sea) moisture is getting evaporated into the air then carried *away* that's why barring a few anomalies so many of the big deserts are on or near the 30° lines on the globe > he'll not get the nice sharp demarcation he's looking for it will be big broad desert becoming slowly less dry the further out you go, not what he's after.

Comment: @spaff you should probably ask that as its own question first. Tilt, thickness of the atmosphere and temp all play a role.

Comment: @Pelinore except there is still a eastward wind bringing moisture in from the coast, and it can over power mild rain shadow, which is why lake Victoria is still there. the whole area has to be dry for this to work. with the right angle they can get a double rain shadow with temperate forest on ither side and desert in between like parts of Patagonia.

Comment: @Pelinore the Hadley cells are only part of the equation, remember there are jungles at 30 degrees in some places. but you need a drying effect of the horse latitudes to get a desert that large.

Comment: @John Sure, but I was going for the simplest model I could think of because anything more complex was going to take me too much time researching and likely cause my brain to melt ;D I'd love to see a more in depth answer if someone can do one, to be honest I was hoping my answer would serve to encourage someone better able to give an answer ;)

Comment: @Pelinore fair, time is the reason I didn't make an answer, that and now realizing the any answer should wait for several prelude questions.

Answer (score 1):

Probably.

Earthlike doesn't mean an exact replica of Earth.  There are a lot of things that could change the way weather patterns work on a "New Earth" planet, even if most other things are the same.  Some things to consider:

- Volume/Mass: Either of these would offer possible changes to how weather patterns work and even how things like "rain shadows" might propogate.
- Density/composition of atmosphere: Similar to the above, a more voluminous planet that is Earthlike may have a slightly less dense atmosphere which could potentially make it slightly dryer.  That doesn't necessarily mean it isn't a blue-green planet.  With a less dense atmosphere, there could be much more surface/subsurface water which would still allow for a blue-green planet, but less filtering of energy from the star could also create less cloud cover and less atmospheric moisture.
- Then there's the way that Earthlike jet-streams and gulf-streams are an objective aspect specifically of Earth and our geography rather than a set aspect of an Earthlike planet.  We know that modern deserts have been oceans, and modern rainforests have been plains.  The makeup of our regional climates are specific to air and sea currents, mountain ranges, ice flows, volcanoes, land masses, CO2-O2 exchanges due to forests and sea life (algae), and numerous other things.  Even minute changes to any of these could provide exactly what you're looking for, and on another Earth that was exactly the same but for small tweaks to any of these, the climate could look very different.

Comment: *"Then there's the way that Earthlike jet-streams .. We know that modern deserts have been oceans"* sure, but there's no relation between oceans and jet streams, oceans are due to elevation and nothing to do with the weather, wind patterns, climate or rainfall above them // things like volcanic activity and plate tectonics are what push land above sea level and the water just trickles from wherever it fell to the low points we call oceans.